# Why is my next.config.js breaking my heroku build?

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, webpack, next.js

I am able to run the project locally, but ever since I changed `next.config.js` file to include `@zeit/next-css` my heroku build is failing and giving me the following error.

```
remote: Error: webpack build failed: found page without a React Component as default export in pages/gql/queries/age-ranges.js
```

And this is the content of my config file.  The two commented out sections are other configurations I've tried that also failed.

**next.config.js**

```
const withImages = require('next-images');
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css');

module.exports = withCSS(withImages());

// ---- -----

// const withPlugins = require('next-compose-plugins');
// const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css');
// const withImages = require('next-images');

// const nextConfig = {
//  useFileSystemPublicRoutes: false,
//  webpack: config => {
//      config.node = {
//          fs: 'empty',
//          modules: false
//      };

//      return config;
//  }
// };

// module.exports = withPlugins([withCSS, withImages], nextConfig);

// ----- synapse -----

// const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css');
// const withImages = require('next-images');
// module.exports = withCSS(withImages());

// module.exports = withCSS(
//  withImages({
//      target: 'serverless',
//      webpack(config) {
//          config.module.rules.push({
//              test: /\.(png|svg|eot|otf|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
//              use: {
//                  loader: 'url-loader',
//                  options: {
//                      limit: 8192,
//                      publicPath: '/_next/static/',
//                      outputPath: 'static/',
//                      name: '[name].[ext]'
//                  }
//              }
//          });
//          return config;
//      }
//  })
// );
```

**/gql/queries/age-ranges.js**

```
import gql from 'graphql-tag';

export const GET_AGE_RANGES = gql`
    query getAgeRanges {
        allAgeRanges {
            nodes {
                name
                nodeId
                id
            }
        }
    }
`;
```

Comment: Can you publish your pages/gql/queries/age-ranges.js file?

Comment: For sure.  I added it to the original post, but I don't think it's the source of the issue.  I didn't have the error occur until I added `withCSS` to my config file.  If I remove it from the file the build works just fine, but he app crashes on certain pages because I need the css loader for a component I imported

Comment: I read some issues on github and this trouble looks like https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/7836 If it's true you can't put non-pages resources in your pages folder

Comment: Try to move age-ranges to other place and run it again

Comment: I've done that and then it just mentions a new file with the same error.  I have actually been able to narrow it down a little more.  The error is occurs when I update my `next` package from `8.1.0` to a newer version `9.1.5-canary.8`, but I need the newer version so that I can import `react-flatpickr`.

Comment: I think you need correct your answer and you can ask help at nextjs issues on github, I can't help you, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue.  Calendar picker CSS I imported was throwing an error but it was fixed when I updated Next to a more current version.  But when I updated to the 'canary' version of next the build was failing because they require a different file structure.